# Check whether Location Service enabled from a BroadcastReceiver in Android

Tags: android, location, broadcastreceiver, google-location-services

I need to check if location setting is enabled or not inside `onReceive()` method of my `BroadcastReceiver` to get the location update and use the location to proceed further. I know how to do this from an Activity using `LocationManager` or `SettingsApi` but how to do the same from `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: what actually you want to do ?explain everything

Comment: You can use LocationManager in Broadcast receiver

Answer (score 0):

You can check for location service enabled as follows:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean gps_enabled = false;
boolean network_enabled = false;

try {
    gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
} catch(Exception ex) {}

try {
    network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
} catch(Exception ex) {}
if(gps_enabled || network_enabled ){
    //Do something.
}
```